# json file loading with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, json

This is my jquery code

```
$("document").ready(function() {
        $.getJSON("http://bluewingholidays.com/results.json", function(data) {
            $("#div-my-table").text("<table>");
            $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                $("#div-my-table").append("<tr><td>" + item.EncoderName + "</td><td>" + item.EncoderStatus + "</td></tr>");
            });
            $("#div-my-table").append("</table>");
        });
    });
```

i want to display data into the web  using html table

```
<table id="div-my-table">
    <tr><td></td></tr>
     <tr><td></td></tr>
     <tr><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

but nothing happened ?

Comment: Is there anything in `data`?

Comment: i'm new to json.can you help me to understand ?

Comment: Is this code running on `bluewingholidays.com`?

Comment: bluewingholidays.com was created using joomla and it is slow now .so i want to use json fetch data to create an extension..

Comment: @sami: That doesn't answer my question.  Is this code running on that site, or not?

Comment: no i was testing it in the fiddle.I know that thing is not allowed

Comment: neither item.EncoderName nor item.EncoderStatus are a part of theat JSON object - it contains "id", "title" and "price" for each row of the "Properties" object array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make the assumption your table already exists, so this should work:

```
<table id="div-my-table">    </table>
```

and in your  script process the returned JSON:

```
$.each(data.Properties, function(i, item) {
    $("#div-my-table").append("<tr><td>" + item.id + ":" + item.title +  "</td><td>" + item.price + "</td></tr>");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

One problem i see right off the bat is you need to change `$("document")` to `$(document)`. You want to pass the document object not a selector.

```
$(document).ready(function(){...
```

Comment: @sami: You can't just load arbitrary URLs with jQuery.  That's against the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: Sami, the console reveals why `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://bluewingholidays.com/results.json. Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

Answer (score 1):

`append` does not append some arbitrary text (and in particular not `</table>`) in jQuery! It appends an element... You should rather use such code :

```
// Content will contain the HTML code of your new table
var content = "";

$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    content += "<tr><td>" + item.EncoderName + "</td><td>" + item.EncoderStatus + "</td></tr>";
});   

// Set the HTML of your table to this new content
$("#div-my-table").html(content);
```

Comment: I agree for a valid HTML fragment but not for some partial code. You can try with : http://jsfiddle.net/qmkrY/1/ (on firefox, the source code of the updated table does not contain the first `</td>`).

Comment: I realized what was really going on and removed my comment :P

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of different issues here.

First, `$("document").ready(` should be `$(document).ready(`.  Lose the quotes.  You want to pass the `document` object, not a selector.

Second, this code won't work if this code is not running on `bluewingholidays.com`.  That's called the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Third, that's not how you append elements in jQuery.  (Note: `.text` is for changing the text of an element, if you send it HTML, it will be escaped.)

When you append HTML in jQuery, you don't first append the open tag, then the close tag.  jQuery expects you to send complete HTML, not fragments.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // This will only work if this code is on bluewingholidays.com
    $.getJSON("http://bluewingholidays.com/results.json", function(data) {
        $("#div-my-table").empty(); // this is already a table, so let's empty it
        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            // You're appending HTML elements to other HTML elements
            // You are not appending text in the way you think
            $("#div-my-table").append("<tr><td>" + item.EncoderName + "</td><td>" + item.EncoderStatus + "</td></tr>");
        });
        // You append HTML elements, not strings, so you don't need this line
        //$("#div-my-table").append("</table>");
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, good summary! But be careful : 1. this is `.html("<table></table>")` (with a `/` before the 2nd "table"), 2. `div-my-table` seems to be already a table in the OP code, so no need to create a new table, 3. I think that this code will be DOM expensive if a lot of elements are appended...

Comment: @SamuelCaillerie: The lack of `/` was just a typo.  Ah, you're right about the OP's HTML.  Let me fix that.